# What is the Biblical basis for death being the last point for repentance?

Tags: biblical-basis, heaven, hell, death, judgment

Death is seen as a point at which our eternal destiny is decided or the last point for repentance, at least in most evangelical circles.

What is the Biblical basis for this belief?

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match your question body. The last point of repentance is believed to be before death.

Comment: Thanks @curiousdannii, I've amended the question a little

Answer (score 3):

**What is the Biblical basis for death being the last point for repentance?**

Before death is the time when we do that which can be judged. Judgment of works for punishment is what comes to those who have rejected Jesus.

> Hebrews 9:27  And as it is appointed unto men once to die, but after
>   this the judgment:

The time to "know" Jesus is while we are alive.

> Matthew 7:22-23  Many will say to me in that day, Lord, Lord, have we
>   not prophesied in thy name? and in thy name have cast out devils? and
>   in thy name done many wonderful works?   And then will I profess unto
>   them, I never knew you: depart from me, ye that work iniquity.

Judgment of works for reward is what comes to Christians.

> 1 Corinthians 3:13-15  Every man's work shall be made manifest: for
>   the day shall declare it, because it shall be revealed by fire; and
>   the fire shall try every man's work of what sort it is.   If any man's
>   work abide which he hath built thereupon, he shall receive a reward.
>   If any man's work shall be burned, he shall suffer loss: but he
>   himself shall be saved; yet so as by fire.

The "repentance" associated with salvation may be more of an effect rather than a cause. The word in Greek means a change of mind. Those who have been saved reflect a mind that has been changed as a result of being born again and having a new nature.

God can offer anyone this salvation at any time even right before death. Salvation requires the action of God.

> John 6:44  No man can come to me, except the Father which hath sent me
>   draw him: and I will raise him up at the last day.

Salvation does not seem to rest solely upon our decision to change our mind (repentance).